# F_SEAL_SEAL undeclared, even when headers are included

Tags: c, linux, fcntl

I'm trying to use file sealing on Linux. Here's an example C program.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void) {
    (void)F_SEAL_SEAL;
}
```

You can build it using `gcc -Wall -o ./linux_file_sealing linux_file_sealing.c` or similar.

When I build it, I get an error about `F_SEAL_SEAL`.

```
gcc -Wall -o ./linux_file_sealing linux_file_sealing.c
linux_file_sealing.c: In function ‘main’:
linux_file_sealing.c:7:19: error: ‘F_SEAL_SEAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf("%d\n",F_SEAL_SEAL);
                   ^
linux_file_sealing.c:7:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I'm including `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h`, as per the man page... so what else should I be doing, and where is that described?

(The man pages just say that sealing is "Linux-specific", but give no further details. This is the reason for including the `GNU_SOURCE` define, which is how you get the other Linux-specific stuff, but for `F_SEAL_SEAL` it seems to make no difference.)

(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Linux 4.4.0-36)

Comment: Exactly which man-page are you referring to, please?

Comment: The one I get from `man fcntl`. Looks to be this one: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html - but I didn't check every char!

Comment: I filed a man page bug for this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: Nops, I found it on [searchcode](https://searchcode.com/?q=F_SEAL_SEAL%20repo:mirrors/linux-2.6)

Comment: Link noted, thanks - I'm sure that will prove useful.